# ubuntu - pantheon-files gone after restart

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04

I tried to customize ubuntu's file explorer by installing pantheon-files. Everything is working. But after rebooting, the file explorer returns to the default view

I've tried installing again, reinstall, uninstall then install. The result is still the same. File Explorer uses default files

I want to use Pantheon files

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. SO is for _programming_ questions. You might have better luck on [su], [unix.se], or [ubuntu.se].